# programmers notepad is missing when installing winavr

Tags: windows, avr, winavr

i installed winavr and tried to open programmers notepad but iam getting :

```
pn.exe is not found.
```

and the pn folder is empty.
Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When installing WinAVR, the installer pops up a dialog with some check-boxes.  Check the "Install Programmers Notepad" box.

Depending on the WinAVR version (and hence depending on PN's version), the executable is named pn.exe or pn2.exe.